# Emotion or Expression words meaning Dictionary

Tags: word-meaning, expressions, american-english

When I watch TV with my closed captioned on, and sometimes there are words that I want to know what it means.  My question is Are there some good sites that will help me what the Emotion or Expression words means ?

By emotion or expression words I mean words like Grr, Arrgh, scream, snore etc.

What are the term for that?

I am hearing impaired and sometimes there are a few words that I don't understand.

Like for example, when someone is mad we know what it is but there are some words that I have not heard before .

My first language is American Sign Language but I can write English ok.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by "Emotion or Expression word".  Can you give an example of some such words.  Do you mean "words" like "Grrr" or "Arrgh"?

Comment: Yes that sort of thing like Grr, Arrgh , scream , snore etv  like a face expression but in words only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the words you give, snore and scream are perfectly regular words which are defined in dictionaries.  Of course, the dictionary definition is written for hearing people. It is probably impossible to describe a sound to a profoundly deaf person who has never heard sound:

Snore is in the dictionary as "a snorting or grunting sound while asleep" I don't know if that helps. https://www.handspeak.com/word/search/index.php?id=2829

and scream is "long, loud, piercing cry or cries expressing extreme emotion or pain." (Lexico) https://www.handspeak.com/word/search/index.php?id=1898

The other examples, "Grrr" and "Arrgh" are representations of sounds that people make.  Sometimes they get listed in regular dictionaries

> Grrr: used to express anger or annoyance. (Lexico)

> Argh: https://www.handspeak.com/word/search/index.php?id=6621

There is a dictionary of such *interjections* and *exclamations* https://www.vidarholen.net/contents/interjections/

Comment: Thank you ! That is what I am looking for. Those two words  ( interjections and exclamations) are what I need to look it up for.